# Arduino undesirable incoming serial datas from SPI

Tags: serial-port, arduino, nfc, spi

I'm working with Arduino with a NFC Shield ([this one](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/nfc-shield-p-916.html)). I'm trying to use interrupts on Rx: I want my Arduino to wake up, each it receives data on serial line. This works correctly without the NFC shield. However, with the NFC shield, it sends '0' on the serial port, triggering an interrupt, which I really don't want.

After some research, I discovered that each time the library writes on the SPI pins (like `digitalWrite(_clk, LOW);`, it returns '0'.

In the loop function, I have this line:

```
id = NFC.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A);
```

So, each time this line is executed, a '0' is sent through the serial bus, and the Arduino never goes into sleep mode... (even if there is no NFC card to read)

Does someone know why? And how can I avoid it?